# How do I remove transactions subsystem from JBoss7?

Tags: apache-camel, jboss7.x

I am "slimming" down a JBoss7 server for a Camel based microservice. One of my goals is to remove the number of ports being used. When I try to remove the transactions subsystem I see the following error:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.txn.ArjunaRecoveryManager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.connector.transactionintegration] 
  service jboss.txn.ArjunaTransactionManager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.connector.bootstrapcontext.default] 
  service jboss.txn.TransactionManager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.connector.transactionintegration] 
  service jboss.txn.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.connector.transactionintegration] 
  service jboss.txn.UserTransactionRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.connector.transactionintegration] 
  service jboss.txn.XATerminator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.connector.workmanager.default, service jboss.connector.transactionintegration, service jboss.connector.bootstrapcontext.default]
```

I do want to deploy ActiveMQ RAR in here so I think I will need the connector subsystem. So does that mean I will need to keep the transactions subsystem as well? If anyone has experience with slimming down the JBoss standalone especially for Camel, please let me know what you use.

Here is a Gist for the standalone: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/02320dc22b02a733c168#file-standalone-microservice-xml

Comment: Why not just run your routes on Karaf? Deploying your routes to Karaf is so easy it should be illegal.

Comment: He is not asking about Karaf that is offtopic in this Q

Comment: Just a note that there is a new wildfly-camel module in the works for wildfly users - so in the future this may come out of the box, and easier to do Camel on JBoss - https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS7 starts only the services that are needed. So if you do not use WebServices, for example, the CXF stack is not started and so on. Therefore the blazing fast boot of JBoss AS7.

ActiveMQ requires transactions since they are required by JCA (Java EE Connector Architecture). It might be a better approach not to use JBoss from that what you are writing. Spring Boot/Dropwizard/Plain Tomcat or even Karaf.

If you want to get rid of ports, you should switch to WildFly. In addition to that, you can bind the unused ports to 127.0.0.1